# Python - внедрить строку из файла в код программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот допустим у меня есть простой код.

```
print("Gold: " + str(gold))
```

И есть файл const.txt
В нём записано:

```
gold = 100
```

И нужно чтобы программа забрала это значение, или лучше создать .ini?

Comment: Назовите файл const.py и импортируйте в программу

Comment: Мне нужно систему Save/Load забабахать, а для этого нужно сохранить файл с значениями

Comment: Сохраняйте, что мешает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создаем файл settings.json

   {"gold": 100, "silver": 30, "cuprum": 1000}

Будем хранить параметры в виде пары ключ:значение (словарь) и использовать JSON для хранения.

2. Пример программы

   ```
   import json

   def load_settings(filename):
       with open(filename) as json_file:
           settings = json.load(json_file)
       return settings

   def save_settings(settings, filename):
       with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
           json.dump(settings, outfile)


   settings=load_settings("settings.json")
   print(settings["gold"])

   settings["silver"]=1000   
   save_settings(settings, "settings.json")
   ```